# How can I make current Data and time show up in cell a1 and c1 respectively when I type a text in cell b1?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

am using sheets and I want my cell to auto-populate with the date today in one cell and the time now to populate in another, so this is what I've tried doing.

I added the forumla in column C to show the time now, using the NOW() function, but it returns both date and time, when I only want the time, and everytime I make a new entry in Column B or anywhere in the sheet the entire Column C updates as show in the picture having the same seconds

In column A I added this formula =IF(ISTEXT(B1), TODAY(), "") it show the exactly what I want but I don't know if it will update the entire column once I enter a new data in column B the next day.

[What I got got from trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqpTq.png)

The result I want my sheet to do is this one.

[What I want my sheet to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWi0V.png)

It's a real life example on how this sheet will be used, it's like a logging entry for employees, like a tracker,whenever they put their name on Column B, Column A and C, should auto populate with the Date now, and the current time they entered their name, and it should not update when someone else updates the sheet with their own entry.

Comment: You can create a different cell to keep the previous data and if they don't match just update the time with a excel function.

Comment: search for "timestamp script"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are ok to turn on Iterative Calculations, then you can try this...

1. Open the google sheets file.
2. Click `File` in the top menu bar
3. Go to `Settings`
4. Change to the `Calculation` tab
5. Set `Max number of iterations` to `1`
6. Click `Save settings`
7. Put this formula into cell `C1`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($B:$B),"",IF(C:C="",NOW(),C:C)))
```

8. Select the entire column `C`
9. Click `Format`
10. Hover over `Number`
11. Select `Time`

NOTE: You can change the time format to whatever custom format you like.

To do the same for the date, just change the formula to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($B:$B),"",IF(A:A="",NOW(),A:A)))
```

and put it into cell `A1`
Then follow steps 8-11 as above, but selecting column `A` and using a `Date` format

NOTE: If you get a date for the year 1899 in cell A1, then copy the data from cell B1, then delete the contents of cell B1, then paste it back in again, and it will return the current date/time.

Comment: It works for 1 row

https://screenbud.com/s/YAlQOLEad64

but I get this error when try to use it in more than 1 row/column

screenbud.com/shot/adb684e3-4159-46b8-805b-57427fe96cd3

Comment: you can not have any other data in any cells under the first cell.. it is an arry formula, so it automatically fills all the cells below it when necessary.. do NOT drag the formula down to other cells.. follow the instruction.. ONLY put the formula in cell A1  or C1.